# Angularjs libs Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

Hello guys ı am new with angular.js and checked alot of possible solutions but it didnt work.

I add them as same in the ı saw in the project

they are all  in the vendor Directory

```
script src="vendor/angular.js"></script

script src="vendor/angular-strap.js"></script
```

and when ı click Ctrl and mouse it sees the files and it can be opened so their positions are right , but the project cant see them. Thank you

ı tried a lot things like `../../` but didint work, do you think the Gulp can be broken but it works correctly

I cant give image cuz of having less then 10 post. But Errors like:

http://localhost:****/vendor/angular-cookies.js

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost:63342/app.js

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

it gives the error all angular libs and my files like app.js, style.css, show.js

Thank you so much.

Comment: Has nothing to do with angular which is code that is contained in those files that runs in the browser. Sounds like project configuration problem or server config problem

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to set a base path:

```
<base href="http://localhost/myproject">
```

Comment: it was <base href="/"> but now, Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED now this happend.

Comment: Is your localhost up and running?

Comment: what do you mean up my friend? but it is running